# How to define an array in RAM 8051 (assembly)?

Tags: assembly, 8051

I would like to define an array in the RAM (data segment).
Trying:

```
RAM segment data
rseg RAM
VEC1:       DS 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ; <-- 8th line
```

When trying to compile I get this error from Keil uVision:
main.A51(8): error A9: SYNTAX ERROR

This compiles fine:

```
RAM segment data
rseg RAM
VEC1:       DS 2
```

Comment: How does it not work and which assembler are you using?

Comment: @Jester I get a syntax error from Keil uVision

Comment: Which is the 8th line?

Answer (score 0):

You want `DB` not `DS`, as `DS` is for reserving the given number of bytes. You can't initialize them. See the [manual](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a51/a51_st_ds.htm).

Comment: You can't use DB in the data segment, only in code segment

Comment: What's the error if you try to do that? It might not be possible to initialize data in RAM, possibly you will have to copy the initializer from flash.

Comment: main.A51(8): error A37: OPERATION INVALID IN THIS SEGMENT